# Can a model of $\sf ZFC$ be a subset of $V_\omega$?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Can a model of $\sf ZFC$ be a subset of $V_\omega$? If so, in which theory this is provable?

Comment: @AlexKruckman, Thanks. So there is such a model, I wonder what is the definition of such a model, I mean what is the hereditarily finite set that stand for $\omega$ in that model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent, then there is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with domain $V_\omega$. Why? By Löwenheim-Skolem, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ has a countable model $M$. Since $V_\omega$ is countable, we can put $M$ into bijection with $V_\omega$ and transfer the membership relation from $M$ to $V_\omega$, turning $V_\omega$ into a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ isomorphic to $M$.

But presumably you are interested in a model with the standard $\in$ relation, i.e. a set $M\subseteq V_\omega$ such that $(M,\in)\models \mathsf{ZFC}$. In that case, the answer is no, since every element of $V_\omega$, (and hence every element of your model) is finite.

You might be thinking of a result known as Ressayre's theorem. I'll state it in a strengthened form due to Joel David Hamkins. See Main Theorem 3 / Theorem 10 in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0219061313500062) ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0963)).

Let $M$ be any non-$\omega$-model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (any model with non-standard $\omega$). Then for every structure $(X,R)$, where $X$ is a countable set and $R$ is an acyclic binary relation on $X$, $(X,R)$ embeds in $(V_\omega^M,\in)$.

In particular, since in every model $(M',\in')$ of ZFC, $\in'$ is an acyclic binary relation, *every* countable model of ZFC is isomorphic to a substructure of $(V_\omega^M,\in)$. Of course, the domain of this substructure $(M'',\in)\cong (M',\in')$ is an *external* subset of $V_\omega^M$. $M$ cannot have the subset $M''$ as an element by the argument in the second paragraph of this answer, carried out in $M$.

In the comments, you ask "what is the hereditarily finite set that stand for $\omega$ in that model?" Well, it's a little hard to say, because there will actually be many embeddings $f\colon (M',\in')\to(V_{\omega}^M,\in)$. Typically, $0$ will map to some element $f(0)\in V_\omega^M$ of non-standard finite size, such that no element of $f(0)$ is in the image of $f$. Then $1$ will map to some element $f(1)\in V_\omega^M$ of non-standard finite size, such that $f(1)\cap \text{im}(f) = \{0\}$. etc. etc. and $\omega$ will map to $f(\omega)\in V_\omega^M$ such that $f(\omega)\cap \text{im}(f) = \{f(0),f(1),\dots\}$. The point is that in "hereditarily finite" sets of non-standard finite size, there's lots of room (if we're allowed to work externally).